# Magento 2 : Order comment only can select status to "complete" after shipment

Tags: magento2

After shipment generated, I realise that if I have to comment on the order (not in shipment), it will go to  the "complete" state, which I don't want it to. Version is 2.3

[image]?

Comment: After shipment which state you have to need ?

Comment: I may still need to comment on it and not tag it as complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you need like below image order status then you have to create new order status from admin and assign order status to the [image]complete state.

Comment: But that would still put the underlying state of the order to being “completed”. Which is not what I need. I need it to be kept in the “processing” stage. Which is what the order is in. It hasn’t been completed. But to add a comment, it will be driven to become completed.

Comment: if you are in order completed state then you no need to show complete state?